# Incompatibility between geolocator and onesignal_flutter plugins causes unexpected application termination

Tags: android, ios, flutter, plugins, dart

**Steps to Reproduce:**

- Start a new flutter app project
- Add to your pubspec.yaml the following dependencies:

> onesignal_flutter: ^2.0.0
>
> geolocator: ^5.1.3

- run the app
  (Returns an error requesting migration to androidX)
- Finish the app and migrate your project to androidX
- Run the app again

The app will simply stop working during your startup!

Can anyone give me any help as to what may be happening?

**Log flutter doctor**

```
flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.17134.1006], locale pt-BR)
• Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.5 at C:\projects\flutter
• Framework revision 1aedbb1 (6 days ago), 2019-10-17 08:37:27 -0700
• Engine revision b863200c37
• Dart version 2.5.0

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\AGENCIA UNIO DEV\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 40.2.2
• Dart plugin version 191.8593
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] VS Code (version 1.33.1)
• VS Code at C:\Users\AGENCIA UNIO DEV\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 2.26.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
• Lenovo K33b36 • 3b1eda5a • android-arm • Android 7.0 (API 24)

• No issues found!
```

**The only error that is shown**

[image]

**Log in run app**

> 2019-10-23 14:14:42.798 19910-19910/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   2019-10-23 14:14:42.852 19910-19910/com.example.teste_erro2 D/LenovoAppIconTheme: ExtraResources;cleanCachedIcon;clear cache..
>   2019-10-23 14:14:42.878 19910-19910/com.example.teste_erro2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   2019-10-23 14:14:42.880 19910-19910/com.example.teste_erro2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.teste_erro2, PID: 19910
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
>           at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5811)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5403)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5342)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.teste_erro2-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.teste_erro2-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.teste_erro2-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5811) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5403) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5342) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

**I run ./gradlew androidDependencies in my android/ folder**

```
releaseCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- C:\projects\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-arm64-release\flutter.jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:16.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-rc01@jar
+--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-rc01@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-rc01@aar
\--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-rc01@jar

releaseRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:16.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-rc01@jar
+--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-rc01@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-rc01@aar
\--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-rc01@jar

releaseUnitTest
releaseUnitTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:16.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-rc01@jar
+--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-rc01@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-rc01@aar
\--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-rc01@jar

releaseUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:16.0.0@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-rc01@jar
+--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.1@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-rc01@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-rc01@aar
\--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-rc01@jar

> Task :location_permissions:androidDependencies
debug
debugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- C:\projects\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-arm64\flutter.jar
+--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
\--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0@jar

debugRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
\--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0@jar

debugAndroidTest
debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- androidx.multidex:multidex-instrumentation:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0@jar
\--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0@aar

debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- androidx.multidex:multidex-instrumentation:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0@jar
\--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0@aar

debugUnitTest
debugUnitTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
\--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0@jar

debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
\--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0@jar

profile
profileCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- C:\projects\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-arm64-profile\flutter.jar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0@jar
\--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0@aar

profileRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0@jar
\--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0@aar

profileUnitTest
profileUnitTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
\--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0@jar

profileUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
\--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0@jar

release
releaseCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- C:\projects\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-arm64-release\flutter.jar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0@jar
\--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0@aar

releaseRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0@jar
\--- androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0@aar

releaseUnitTest
releaseUnitTestCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
\--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0@jar

releaseUnitTestRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.2@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0@jar
\--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0@jar

> Task :onesignal_flutter:androidDependencies
debug
debugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- C:\projects\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-arm64\flutter.jar
+--- com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.11.4@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-license:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location-license:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:12.0.1@aar
+--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-rc01@jar
+--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01@jar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-license:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common-license:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:12.0.1@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-rc01@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-rc01@aar
\--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-rc01@jar

debugRuntimeClasspath - Dependencies for runtime/packaging
+--- com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.11.4@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:12.0.1@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-license:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location-license:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:12.0.1@aar
+--- androidx.media:media:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-rc01@jar
+--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01@jar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-license:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common-license:12.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:12.0.1@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0-rc01@aar
+--- androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0-rc01@jar
+--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-rc01@aar
\--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-rc01@jar
```

Comment: please report it https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration#im-having-issues-migrating-to-androidx

Answer (score 0):

After a few days searching I found that the problem was the incompatibility of play-services dependencies and then searching the right way found the answer in:

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/27#issuecomment-428011934